# Force process to run in 32-bit mode in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, application-pool, iis-8.5

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which is compiled and deployed using "Any CPU".
It is deployed on IIS 8.5.9600.16385 on Windows Server 2012 R2 64-bit Standard.

In IIS Manager -> Application Pools -> My Application Pool -> Advanced Settings, I have set to true the setting "Enable 32-bit Applications".

So As far as I know, If that's true, that means the worker process is forced to run in 32-bit. If the setting is false, then the app pool is running in 64-bit mode. So in my case, process is running in 32-bit (as I have set that setting to true) but If I open up Task Manager and check w3wp.exe process it is shown as w3wp.exe instead of w3wp*32.exe? Why? Does it mean process is not running in 32-bit and in fact it is running in 64-bit?

Anyway, I have noticed that if setting "Enable 32-bit Applications" is true, then w3wp.exe process is pointing to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv (this path is shown in process properties in task manager) whereas if this setting is false, then it is pointing to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv.

So can I make the following assumptions?

- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv --> It means that w3wp.exe is a 32-bit
  process running in 32-bit mode.
- C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv --> It means that w3wp.exe is a 64-bit
  process running in 64-bit mode.

Maybe the w3wp.exe was being shown as w3wp*32.exe in task manager when running in 32-bit mode in previous versions of IIS? and in the most recent IIS versions now this process is always shown as w3wp.exe independently whether it is running in 32-bit or 64-bit mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the running result of the MVC application which is compiled and deployed using "Any CPU", if enable 32-bit application is false, the application is running in 64-bit, and true is running in 32-bit. About "Any CPU", you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52959843/14162739).

[image: 64-bit]
[image: 32-bit]

The running process of both is w3wp.exe, but under different folders, as you found. How to run the early IIS can not be found now, only the system before win7 is the early version of IIS, and the 64-bit operating mode has always been recommended by Microsoft.

In the latest version of IIS, no matter whether the process is 32-bit or 64-bit, it always runs as w3wp.exe, and you can't find w3wp*32.exe in the system disk.
[image]

So for your initial question, running w3wp.exe from syswow64 does not mean that the process is running on 64-bit, it depends on the application itself. Because MVC is set to Any CPU, it is 32-bit in this case. If the application itself forces 64-bit to run, it also can run because of [Process Interoperability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/process-interoperability).

Here are the code in MVC, you can test it if you want.

```
public ActionResult About()
    {
        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
        {
            ViewBag.message = "32-bit";
        }else if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        {
            ViewBag.message = "64-bit";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.message = "nothing";
        }
        return View();
    }
public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
            Response.Write("64-bit process");
        else
            Response.Write("32-bit process");

        return View();
    }
```